# Very slow Internet thru 3 different routers, fast with just DSL modem

Tags: networking, router, internet, ping

I see very slow internet when my laptop is cabled thru a router--ping time ranges between 1,000 and 2,500 ms!

When I connect ethernet directly to DSL modem and sign into PPPoE, the ping time is under 50 ms so it's not an ISP problem.

I have tried 3 different routers with the same result. (The routers are an old Linksys, an old Netgear, and a newish TP-Link, all with factory firmware.) So it seems unlikely it's a router problem.

Wi-fi to the router is likewise slow.

Ping time to the router's IP is 7 ms.

I have tried several different ethernet cables, old and new.

So it doesn't seem to be a router problem, or a cable problem, or a Win10/laptop problem.

Any thoughts on what the cause might be?? Thank you all very much.

Comment: So you are putting the PPPoE credentials in the router? What is your MTU size setting, did you lower it to 1452 in the router?

Comment: When you connect a router to the DSL modem, do you switch the DSL modem into a simple bridging modem mode, and configure your router to act as the PPPoE client? If not, you're almost certainly doing double NAT, and as acejavelin suggested, you probably have an MTU size problem and your DSL modem is probably too stupid to do support MSS clamping or Path MTU Discovery correctly.

Comment: The router is configured as the PPPoE client. The MTU is 1480 which I have never adjusted.
The modem (Actiontec T2200M) will be in whatever the factory default mode is, unless my ISP changed it before they shipped it to me. I will log into the admin GUI and report back.

Comment: One new point: I am running a utility that pings Google & Level 3 DNSs every 20 sec and logs the time. The ping time is relatively stable over hours but it does change. At about 16:40, the ping time decreased from about 900 to about 40 over a period of about 2 minutes where it stayed until 18:55. Then until 19:02 it was about 400. Then it went back down to about 40. (It's now 19:09.) 
Thank you for your insights & help!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before, and new routers didn't solve my issue. In my case, the problem was [bufferbloat](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/What_can_I_do_about_Bufferbloat/).

> Bufferbloat is high latency (or lag) that occurs when there’s other
>   traffic on your network.

I had to install new firmware on my router that supported Smart Queue Management. Now I can download massive files while maintaining a stable ping.

Take [this test](http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest)  and note the `bufferbloat` score.

If you get a grade less than a 'c', then bufferbloat may be your issue. Follow the instructions [here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/traffic-shaping/sqm).

> Install LEDE 17.01 or newer, and follow the video at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvYhifdQ92Q

It involves installing new  router firmware, something that supports SQM. OpenWrt is a bit more involved than factory firmware, but the documentation should be able to help you out.

Comment: http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest gives me an F on bufferbloat.
Thank you for all your informative comments and links!
I guess I have router firmware to update. :)